# How to add days interval dynamically between date range

Tags: php, datetime

I want to print all dates between given date range within their interval.But i am adding 2 days if there is any saturday, and adding 1 day more if any sunday between them.

**For ex -**

1) 30/07/2018 is my start date.than add 5 days.

2) 06/08/2018 is the second coming date,than add 5 days to 06/08/2018,So it may be 11/08/2018 but 11/08 and 12/08 are sat and sunday,so add two days,so next date will be

3) 13/08/2018 is my third date like wise... 13/08/2018 + 5days = 18/08/2018 but 18/08 and 19/08 is sat and sunday, so add 2 days more.

4) 20/08/2018 is my fourth date....like wise.

5) 27/08/2018 is my last date bcoz its my end date.

6) Finish

**Plz help me to achieve my expected output**

**Expected output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [month_year] => 30/07/2018
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [month_year] => 06/08/2018
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [month_year] => 13/08/2018
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [month_year] => 20/08/2018
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [month_year] => 27/08/2018
        )
)
```

**Below is my code**

```
public function testdate(){
            $date_from = new \DateTime("7/30/2018");
            $date_to = new \DateTime("8/27/2018");
            $interval = new \DateInterval("P5D");
            $dates = new \DatePeriod($date_from, $interval, $date_to);
            $out = array();
            if (!empty($dates)) {
                foreach($dates as $dt) {
                    $curre = $dt->format('D');
                    if($curre == 'Sat'){
                        $dt->add(new \DateInterval('P2D'));                       
                    }
                    if($curre == 'Sun'){
                        $dt->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
                    }
                    $out[] = array(
                            'month_year' => $dt->format('d/m/Y')
                    ); 
                    //print_r($out);exit;                                     
                }
            }  
            '<pre>';
            //$out = array_reverse($out);
            print_r($out); 
            '</pre>'; 
            exit;           
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather resign from using `\DatePeriod` if there are some non-standard requirements, and go with `do...while` loop. Something like this:

```
function dates_between(\DateTime $date_from, \DateTime $date_to) {
    // always reset the time when working only with dates
    $date_from->setTime(0, 0);
    $date_to->setTime(0, 0);

    $dates_between = [];
    $current_dt = $date_from;
    do {
        $dates_between[] = [
            'month_year' => $current_dt->format('d/m/Y'),
        ];

        $current_dt->add(new \DateInterval('P5D'));

        if ($current_dt->format('D') === 'Sat') {
            $current_dt->add(new \DateInterval('P2D'));
        }
        elseif ($current_dt->format('D') === 'Sun') {
            $current_dt->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
        }
    } while ($current_dt <= $date_to);

    return $dates_between;
}

print_r(
    dates_between(
        new \DateTime('7/30/2018'),
        new \DateTime('8/27/2018')
    )
);
```